# how do i bind two different IP addresses to single Linux server?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I have a web application running on apache2/Linux Redhat which downloads some files from an external FTP server. When the app connects to the FTP server i need to use a different fixed IP address. The purpose is to give a different IP to the FTP server administrator so they will enable it in their firewall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Binding is the easy part:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 1.2.3.5 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And then add that IP address to your apache config

```
Listen 1.2.3.5:80
```

However, chances are real good that your server already listens on the extra IP address. You can tell this if your httpd.conf file has this in it:

```
Listen 80
```

Which tells the server to listen on port 80 of any IP address the server has.

The trickier part is getting your web-app to use that IP address on the outbound connection. Unless you take steps, outbound connections will likely use whatever is bound to "eth0" instead of "eth0:0". Your socket-building API may allow selecting either an interface or an IP address as part of the setup, your mileage may vary.

However, if you're behind a NAT gateway (if the server's actual IP address starts with 10, 172, or 192 this is a sure sign) and not binding publicly routeable addresses to your web-server things get more complicated. In that case your border device needs to be smart enough to know that traffic destined to a specific IP address needs to be rewritten as if it were coming from a second public IP address bound to the firewall. If your firewall/NAT can't do that, you may very well be out of luck.

Comment: ip rule can handle that for you, I will dig up the scripts I wrote for a radio station for this very task.

Comment: is it possible make apache2 host to use that IP ?

Comment: how can i use IP Rule for that ? can you point me :) thanks!

Comment: @Taras the `Listen 192.168.27.2:80` line in the httpd.conf file will tell it to listen to that specific IP address. You probably have `Listen 80` in there which tells it to listen to any address you have added. The specific version tells it to bind specifically.

Comment: Then what IP will see the external FTP server's firewall ? the global IP bound to 192.168.27.2 ? the task is more on to show the firewall different IP.

Comment: thanks for replies, but i still have no idea how to proceed. should i try to rewrite the IP in iptable or try it with ip rule ?

Comment: @Taras I don't know Redhat well enough to give you a command-by-command guide to what you're asking. Sorry.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 12.04 server with default apache config I didn't have to change the config at all or even restart it. Just adding the virtual NIC was all that was needed. I have some stuff in .htaccess, but otherwise, nothing changed in the config.